# XSL: How best to store a node in a variable and then use it in future xpath expressions?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to be able to store a node set in variable and then perform more filting/sorting on it afterward. All the examples I've seen of this involve either using XSL2 or extensions neither of which are really an option.

I've a list of hotels in my XML doc that can be sorted/filtered and then paged through 5 at a time. I'm finding though I'm repeating alot of the logic as currently I've not found a good way to store node-sets in xsl variable and then use xpath on them for further filtering/sorting.

This is the sort of thing I'm after (excuse the code written of the top of my head so might not be 100%):

```
<xsl:variable name="hotels" select="/results/hotels[active='true']" />
<xsl:variable name="3_star_or_less" select="/results/hotels[number(rating) <= 3]" />
<xsl:for-each select="3_star_or_less">
  <xsl:sort select="rating" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Has anyone got an example of how best to do this sort of thing?

Comment: your variable names need changing. XML names must start with letter or underscore. and in `<xsl:for-each select="3_star_or_less">` you would be iterating over child elements (if the names were correct). I think you mean `$three_or_less` or something similar

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<xsl:variable name="hotels" select="/results/hotels[active='true']" />
<xsl:variable name="three_star_or_less"
              select="$hotels[number(rating) &lt;= 3]" />
<xsl:for-each select="$three_star_or_less">
    <xsl:sort select="rating" />
    <xsl:value-of select="rating" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem storing a node-set in a variable in XSLT 1.0, and no extensions are needed. If you just use an XPath expression in `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`, you'll end up doing just that.

The problem is only when you want to store the nodes that *you yourself had generated* in a variable, and even then only if you want to query over them later. The problem here is that nodes you output don't have type "node-set" - instead, they're what is called a "result tree fragment". You can store that to a variable, and you can use that variable to insert the fragment into output (or another variable) later on, but you cannot use XPath to query over it. That's when you need either EXSLT `node-set()` function (which converts a result tree fragment to a node-set), or XSLT 2.0 (in which there are no result tree fragments, only sequences of nodes, regardless of where they come from).

For your example as given, this doesn't seem to be a problem. Rubens' answer gives the exact syntax.

Comment: EXSLT looks like a possibility. I'll have a play around with that, I like the look of just including the node-set functionality on its own: http://www.exslt.org/howto.html#templates

Answer (score 6):

Another note, if you want to be able to use the variable as part of an XPath statement, you need to select into the variable with `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

value-of will only take the text of the node and you wont be able to use the node-set function to return anything meaningful.

```
<xsl:variable name="myStringVar">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- This won't work: -->
<Output>
   <xsl:value-of select="node-set($myStringVar)/SubNode" />
</Output>


<xsl:variable name="myNodeSetVar">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- This will work: -->
<Output>
   <xsl:value-of select="node-set($myNodeSetVar)/SubNode" />
</Output>
```

Comment: Other than that (couldn't edit my comment), thanks for the helpful post. '<xsl:copy-of>' was just what I was looking for!

Comment: You're not answering the original question (where extensions are excluded) since the `node-set()` function is not standard.