# Select specific element from XML by XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this in a variable
**prdxml**

```
 <root>
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8142229</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand"></isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie"></isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model"></isp_model>
  </product>
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8143793</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Bred</isp_model>
  </product> 
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8143794</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Smal</isp_model>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>8143796</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Smal</isp_model>
  </product>
</root>
```

I want to select a product node where id =8143794 from this ,with out using for loop.can any one give any clue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/root/product[id='8143794']
```

That says "find /root/product where the "id" element child to "product" is 8143794"

There's an answer out there as to how to use the variable in a future query: [XSL: How best to store a node in a variable and then us it in future xpath expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954252/xsl-how-best-to-store-a-node-in-a-variable-and-then-us-it-in-future-xpath-expre)

Answer (score 2):

Well with XSLT 1.0 we really need to know whether the type of the variable named `prdxml` is `node-set` or `result tree fragment`.

If it is a node-set you can simply select `$prdxml/root/product[id = 8143794]`. but if you have a result tree fragment you first need to apply an extension function like `exsl:node-set` e.g. `exsl:node-set($prdxml)/root/product[id = 8143794]`.

So check where/how the variable is set, if you have e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="prdxml" select="document('products.xml')"/>
```

you have a node-set, however with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="prdxml">
<root>
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8142229</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand"></isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie"></isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model"></isp_model>
  </product>
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8143793</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Bred</isp_model>
  </product> 
  <product>
    <estocklevel>0</estocklevel>
    <id>8143794</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Smal</isp_model>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>8143796</id>
    <isp_brand extra="isp_brand">Leitz</isp_brand>
    <isp_produktserie extra="isp_produktserie">180</isp_produktserie>
    <isp_model extra="isp_model">Smal</isp_model>
  </product>
</root>
</xsl:variable>
```

you have a result tree fragment and need the second approach (and support for `exsl:node-set`or similar):

```
<xsl:variable name="prod" select="exsl:node-set($prdxml)/root/product[id = 8143794]" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```